# How to plot coordinate points in d3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, d3.js

I have a JSON file with a number of coordinates, like so:

```
[
{
      "coord": [
          184.5247050,
          775.2556777
      ]
}, 
{
      "coord": [
          177.4747474,
          833.2566478
      ]
},
{
      "coord": [
          255.6434553,
          446.7733333
      ]
}
]
```

I use this code with the `d3` library, to try to plot the data on a canvas:

```
var svg = d3.select("#canvas");

d3.json(location_data, function(data){

svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data.coord)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(element, index){
                return index;
                })
                .attr("cy", function(element, index){
                return index;
                })
                .attr("r", 30)
                .attr("fill", "lightgreen");
})
```

But I do not see any output. What is wrong with the code? How do I fix it?

Comment: Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. I [edit]ed the post to remove [irrelevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) discussion. The next step is to try to [diagnose](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem. For example, have you been able to use the `d3` library to draw *anything* on the canvas? Does the callback function appear to get called at all? (For example, if you add a `console.log` to the callback, does the message show up?) Does `data` contain what you expect? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: What version of D3 are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you bind the data using `.data(data.coord)`, but data is an array and has no *coord* attribute. You have to transform your object array to an array containing arrays of coordinates like so:

```
.data(data.map(d => d.coord))
```

You probably also need to change the way you set "cx" and "cy" attributes:

```
.attr("cx", d => d[0])
.attr("cy", d => d[1])
```